# TypeScript no compiling changes

Tags: typescript

I am writing a seeder and I ran into a problem trying to compile it with typescript.

This is my folder structure :

[image]

And this is my tsconfig :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016", /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
    "module": "commonjs", /* Specify what module code is generated. */
    "paths": {
      "@src/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ]
    },
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true, 
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, 
    "strict": true, 
    "skipLibCheck": true 
  },
}
```

I tried running :

```
npx tsc
```

and

```
tsc
```

but neither of them work and seed.ts doesnt change in `dist` folder. I also tried by executing CTRL + SHIFT + B and then compiling it from there but that didnt work too. Any ideas ?

EDIT : For some reason now it compiled and I can see the changes in the dist folder BUT when I run the seeder it is executing its last version for some unexplainable reason ?

Comment: Why would you expect `seed.ts` to change when you compile it?

Comment: Isnt it supposed to compile my whole /src folder into /dist when I compile it ?

Comment: Yes, so it should output some file like `dist/seed.js`, but the compiler should not modify the source file `seed.ts`, otherwise you would lose your source code. And at the bottom of your question you note that you can see the output in the `dist` folder; so the problem seems to be nothing to do with the compilation, and everything to do with how you're running your project after compiling it.

Comment: Oh, it does look like your tsconfig is set up incorrectly though - `src/*` only includes files in the `src` folder, not directories. You want `src/**/*` for that.

Comment: Why there're two prisma folder? Is there any reason why you don't do as what docs said? https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/seed-database

Comment: When I try and do it like that : 
```
"paths": {
      "@src/**/*": [
        "./src/**/*"
      ]
    },
```

It throws me an error saying 
`Pattern '@src/**/*' can have at most one '*' character.`

Comment: @Hoàng Huy Khánh . I use the second prisma file to export prisma